# Python PrettyTable: Add title above the table's header

Tags: python, prettytable

I have a script which generates multiple tables, which all have the same column names and very similar data. Until now I've been making each table unique by printing a title before it, i.e.:

```
print("Results for Method Foo")
#table 1
print("Results for Method Bar")
#table 2
```

and so on. But that's not really pretty..

Although it seems like an obvious use case, I couldn't find anywhere the option to do something like this:

[image: PrettyTable with title]

Any ideas about how I could achieve this?

**Just in case it matters:** I'm using python 3.4 with, with a virtualenv  and prettytable version 0.7.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [PTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable) library, which is originally forked from PrettyTable. I did not find this in the documentation, so it might be useful for others that the syntax is simply as follows:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()

table.title = 'Results for method Foo'
table.field_names = ['Experiment', 'Value']
table.add_row(['bla', 3.14])
table.add_row(['baz', 42.0])

print(table)
```

This gives the desired output:

```
+-------------------------+
|  Results for method Foo |
+---------------+---------+
|   Experiment  |  Value  |
+---------------+---------+
|      bla      |   3.14  |
|      baz      |   42.0  |
+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The table title is not shown. Tested with Python 3.4.3 and following dependencies: tables (3.4.2), prettytable (0.7.2).

Comment: It only works with PTable (see link above, I use version 0.9.2). This is a different package but shares the basic syntax with prettytable since it was originally forked from it.

Comment: After adding the PTable dependency (pip install ptable) it does work. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[As of October 2020](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#prettytable-10---october-4-2020), this is now possible with `prettytable` versions >1.0:

```
table = PrettyTable()
table.title = 'Results for Method Foo'
```