# How to display title in pretty table in python?

Tags: python, prettytable

I was trying to display the title in prettyTable but not sure what is wrong here -

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from prettytable import PrettyTable
hostname = "abc.com"
table = PrettyTable()
table.title = hostname
table.field_names = ['hostname', 'process']
table.add_row(['abc.com', '31324'])
table.add_row(['abc.com', '42230'])
print(table)
```

Output -

```
+----------+---------+
| hostname | process |
+----------+---------+
| abc.com  |  31324  |
| abc.com  |  42230  |
+----------+---------+
```

Expected Output -

```
+----------+---------+
|       abc.com      |
+----------+---------+
| hostname | process |
+----------+---------+
| abc.com  |  31324  |
| abc.com  |  42230  |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PrettyTable: Add title above the table's header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434781/1898437).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using the `prettytable` package (c. 2013) and not the `PTable` package (c. 2015). Both provide the prettytable module. Only the `PTable` package supports table titles.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this doc](http://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/) this should work (not tested):

```
print(table.get_string(title="abc.com"))
```

Comment: yes, I tested, it works this way